# Conditional statements with multiple if statements (Involves raw_input)

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, raw-input

I'm experimenting with raw_input and it works fine except for my 1st `if` statement and my else statement. Whenever I run the code and answer the 2nd question with a raw_input listed after 'League' in the 1st `if` statement, it returns both the 1st if's print and the else's print when it should only print the 1st `if`. Any idea what's wrong?

```
name = raw_input('What is your name?\n')
game = raw_input('\nWhat MOBA do you play/have played? \n(The answer ' \
    'must be case sensitive i.e. LoL for League and DoTA for y\'know the whole darn thing '\
    'is too '\
    'darn long to say even though I typed a lot more than the name)\n')

if game in ('League' , 'League of Legends' , 'LoL'):
    print '\nYou go girl! '
if game in ('DoTA' , 'DoTA 2' , 'DoTA2'):
    print '\nThat\'s cool and all but........ Go play League you dang noob. '
else:
    print '\nAre you kidding me? You play %s? I\'m severely disappointed in you %s.  You ' \
        'should at least be playing ' \
        'one of these popular games. \nShame, shame, shame. Go install one. ' % (game, name)
```

Comment: Instead of the second `if`, use `elif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always use `if` for the first conditional, `elif` for any number of other conditionals (if the input is in the second list in your instance) and `else` if the input is not in any of those lists, your indentation is also a little messed up,nesting if statements inside each other will only run the nested conditional if the first statement is true, I'd also recommend you use the `string.lower()` method on your users input so you don't have to instruct the user to type case-sensitive input and use variables to store those lists so you can reuse them elsewhere in your code..something like this:

```
name = raw_input('What is your name?\n')
game = (raw_input('\nWhat MOBA do you play/have played?')).lower()

awesomeGames=['league' , 'league of legends' , 'lol']
coolGames=['dota' , 'dota 2' , 'dota2']
if game in awesomeGames:
    print '\nYou go girl! '
elif game in coolGames:
    print '\nThat\'s cool and all but........ Go play League you dang noob. '
else:
    print '\nAre you kidding me? You play %s? I\'m severely disappointed in you %s.  You ' \
    'should at least be playing ' \
    'one of these popular games. \nShame, shame, shame. Go install one. ' % (game, name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It does make more sense to go case-insensitive and the code does work better with elif. I always get elif confused with if. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

The indent level is incorrect.
Spend one more space for the second if statement.
or 1 less space and elif instead of the second if.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the second `if` condition by `elif`. `elif` can be used as many times as you want until the condition matches but its better practice to have the last condition as `else` (which is like default statement when other conditions have failed)